# Vuex state not updating in vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am using Vuex store with a state to update a chart (which is a vue component) after manipulating the store state in an external JS file. Problem is the state is populated with data when external JS file calls the mutate function (I have checked it using `console.log`), however when I use a button to update chart with the state data, it shows the by default state data which is in `store.js` file

The `store.js` file has the following code:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
 
Vue.use(Vuex);
 
export default new Vuex.Store({
 state: {
          mercuryData: {
                    type: "line",
                      data: {
                        labels: [12,313,4,2],
                        datasets: [
                          {
                            label: "Number of Messages",
                            data: [],
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(54,73,93,.5)",
                            borderColor: "#36495d",
                            borderWidth: 3
                          },
                        ]
                      },
                      options: {
                        responsive: true,
                        lineTension: 1,
                        scales: {
                          yAxes: [
                            {
                              ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                padding: 25
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                      }
 },
 getters: {},
 mutations: {
          addData (state, payload) {
                    console.log("THIS IS A TEST ")
                    console.log("DO NOT ")
                    console.log(state, payload)
                    console.log("00x0x0x0x0x00x0x0x02")
                    state.mercuryData.data.datasets[0].data.push(0);
                    state.mercuryData.data.labels.push(payload)
                  }
               
 },
 actions: {}
});
```

I am updating data using a loop in external JS file as:

```
import store from '../store/store'
...
...
...
store.commit("addData", 999)
...
```

My vue file with Chart component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas id="planet-chart"></canvas>
    <v-btn color="info" v-on:click="updateData()">Show simulation</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
...
...
  mounted() {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('planet-chart');
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, this.$store.state.mercuryData);

...
...
methods : {
    updateData() {
      myChart.update()
      // planetChartData.data.labels.push(25);
      // planetChartData.data.datasets[0].data.push(24);
      console.log(myChart.data)
      console.log(this.$store.state.mercuryData);
...
...
```

I have also tested it with a button which updates the chart manually and adds the data in store (which is commented at the moment), the data is appended with the by default store state values and not the ones which are running through a loop in external JS file.

I have spent days trying to find a solution but I cannot understand what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use action methods and getters to make this work I assume!

Comment: Yes, you should use the `action` methods.

Comment: There's not enough context to reproduce the problem, as you've stripped out so much that it's not even valid JavaScript. Please update the question to include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I didn't see any action dispatched ?